# How can I save, Key value pair in string variable from response of sampler of Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to save two value as key value pair in List from previous sampler of Jmeter so that I can use that string in pre Preprocessor

Answer (score 0):

Try the below steps:

- Add the 'Regular Expression Extractor" from the Post-Processor
- Define the required variables

Say, for a single variable set the fields in Regular Expression Extractor as below

Field to check => Body

Name of the created variable => username

Regular Expression => username=(.+?)

Template => $1$

Match No => 1

- Now, Pass the variable in the HTTP request > Parameters

Say,

Name = Username

Value = {$username}

- Run the test

Reference: https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/09/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the format of the data you're getting in the response and the format of the data you need to pass in the next request.

In order to get a comprehensive response you should provide at least partial response data and desired at least partial request body

Normally you should use a [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) for extract data from the response:

1. For HTML - [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter/)
2. For JSON - [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor)
3. For XML - [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) or [XPath2 Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath2_Extractor)
4. For everything else - [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) or [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor)

all of them extract values into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which can be used in the next requests